# What is this red dot on the T6 camera body?

Tags: canon, features

What is this red dot next to the viewfinder and live view button on the Canon EOS Rebel T6 (1300D)? I have been unable to find a reference to it online or in the basic or full instruction manuals.

[image: red dot on camera body]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> What is this red dot next to the viewfinder and live view button on the Canon EOS Rebel T6 (1300D)?

A red dot is a common symbol for the record function, and as on other EOS bodies that button serves the dual purpose of starting Live View mode and starting and stopping movie recording. The icon on the button itself is the Live View icon, and I think the red dot next to the button just reminds you of its alternate function in movie mode.

You'll see a similar red dot on the display when the camera is recording a movie.